# Doing a MySQL query with JOINs and get default values if not exists some of them

Tags: mysql

I don't know how exactly name this question, so please read the example and the expected result to clarify.

I need a query that return a list of projects with some data that needs to be joined. Some of the data data that I join, can be NULL. Let me show my actual query:

```
SELECT p.projectid, p.projectname, p.date, u.name, u.surnames
FROM projects p
JOIN rel_user_proj rup ON rup.projectid=p.projectid
JOIN users u ON u.userid=rup.userid
WHERE rup.codrole='PM'
```

The table `rel_user_proj` have relations between projects and users. I can have more than one relation but I only need one so I use the where rup.codrole='PM' that works for me.

The problem is that this table can have NO result for some project but if there is NO result I need to obtain `u.name` and `u.surnames` as NULL.

How I can do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe try with a LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN

Comment: @grunk: Thank you. Doing a LEFT JOIN i get the expected result but only if I delete the condition WHERE rup.codrole='PM'. The problem is that a role doesn't exists is NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go... I think this is your Answer :)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                p.projectid
                , p.projectname
                , p.date
                , tab.name
                , tab.surnames
FROM 
                projects p
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                        rup.projectid
                        , u.name
                        , u.surnames
            FROM users u
            INNER JOIN 
                        rel_user_proj rup 
                                   ON u.userid = rup.userid
         ) tab 
            ON p.projectid = tab.projectid
```

OH woops... and here is the PM clause in it. Also Works.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                p.projectid
                , p.projectname
                , p.date
                , tab.name
                , tab.surnames
FROM 
                projects p
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                        rup.projectid
                        , u.name
                        , u.surnames
            FROM users u
            INNER JOIN 
                        rel_user_proj rup 
                                   ON u.userid = rup.userid
            AND rup.codrole='PM'
         ) tab 
            ON p.projectid = tab.projectid
```

Comment: my pleasure, got there at the end. :) Cheers mate.

Answer (score 1):

LEFT JOIN would be your best option
http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php

SELECT p.projectid, p.projectname, p.date, u.name, u.surnames
FROM projects p
LEFT JOIN rel_user_proj rup ON rup.projectid=p.projectid
JOIN users u ON u.userid=rup.userid
WHERE rup.codrole='PM'

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello @Robbie Tapping: The problem is that if a rel_user_proj doesn't exists (the relation) the codrole will be NULL and I'm selecting codrole='PM' because if exists I need only the codrole='PM'. Any suggestion? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi Mate, do a JOIN between projects and rel_user_proj and do a LEFT JOIN on the user table so SELECT p.projectid, p.projectname, p.date, u.name, u.surnames FROM projects p JOIN rel_user_proj rup ON rup.projectid=p.projectid LEFT JOIN users u ON u.userid=rup.userid WHERE rup.codrole='PM'

so you should now get the projects joining to the rel_user_proj table, but if there are no users you should get NULL's.. HOPEFULLY :)

Comment: argg... No :(. If I do the LEFT JOIN on rel_user_proj (without the WHERE rup.codrole='PM') I get the projects with NULL in name and surnames. If I do the LEFT JOIN in users I don't get this results. So it's okay the LEFT JOIN in the rel_user_projects. The problem is that I need to get codrole='PM' and codrole=NULL

Comment: Do you want a SQL dump with 2 examples for testing?

Comment: ah i think you can do this in mysql but if you LEFT JOIN rel_user_projects rup ON rup.projectid=p.projectid AND rup.codrole="PM" you should be getting your NULLS

Comment: thanks looking now. give me a few minutes, just imported tables

Comment: Can you please type out the Exact result you should be expecting. I cant see how you can have the NULLS in there if you always want to get users that are 'PM' i get NULLS with this query SELECT 
        p.projectid, p.projectname, p.date, u.name, u.surnames
FROM 
        rel_user_proj rup
LEFT JOIN 
        users u ON u.userID = rup.userid
INNER JOIN 
        projects p ON p.projectid = rup.projectid

Comment: Probably I bad explained. The expected result is 2 results: http://pastebin.com/NH3ikVQx . Thank you for your time!